# Is there a minimum MB amount an Apple app is supposed to be

Tags: ios, xcode, appstore-approval

According to my iPhone 5c device my app size is 3.1 MB. When i plug in my iPhones and iPads into Xcode i go to Product then Archive and the App store estimate size of my app is 2.8 MB. I have 5 storyboards, each storyboard with it's own ViewController.h and ViewController.m. Each ViewController has about 1350+ lines of custom code. Plus i have over 40 images of various sizes. How is my app so small? I was expecting 20-25MB. Is there an app store minimum size ? In other words, can my app get rejected automatically if it doesn't meet a certain possible  minimum app store size in MB requirement?

Comment: There is no minimum size restriction.

Comment: There is no minimum size restriction (But your app should have some functionality). For the size thing, check whether your images are being copied to the IPA. Check whether you added those files are copied to your project or just referenced.

Comment: When i drag an image from the Finder, Xcode always gives me a choice to copy items into destination's folder (if needed). I always click on it. Is that what you mean by copying files into folder or are you referring to something else?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app store approval requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app will not get rejected for being to small, they can get rejected for having no functionality though!  I have had apps which were under 1 MB back in the early days.  If you are concerned because you have a bunch of images in the app and expect it to be much larger than 3.1 MB, I would do some investigation to see if the images were added correctly and are in fact going into the app when you archive it.

Comment: How do i do this checking of the images part?

Comment: @Mika You can tap on each image in the project and make sure it is added to the target which you are archiving from.  In the right side bar of Xcode there is a target member ship section in the file inspector tab.

Comment: What version of XCode are you using? I think the newer versions that use xcassets creates a tile map even for non Sprite/SceneKit apps, making the app size smaller. I also think bundles are compressed as well. Only header files are included in the app file, the rest is binary data. Apple probably compress this a lot as well being their data. I wouldn't worry too much. Only keeping under the 50MB limit if needed